# SDL2 - Visual Studio 2017 SDL_FreeWAV Access Violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation

I'm using SDL2, and created an `Audio` class to handle game music and sound effects. The sound works perfectly, but whenever the `Audio` class is destructed, the `SDL_FreeWAV()` call throws an access violation:

> Exception thrown at 0x000000006C7A8737 (SDL2.dll) in Program.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00007FF4A9080008

Audio.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace Audio {

    class Audio {

    public:

        Audio ();
        Audio (char*, char*);
        ~Audio ();

        void pause (int);

    private:

        Uint32 wav_length;
        Uint8 *wav_buffer = NULL;
        SDL_AudioSpec wav_spec;
        SDL_AudioDeviceID device_id;
        int success;

    };

    class Music {

    public:

        Music ();
        Music (char*);
        ~Music ();

    private:

        Audio *audio = NULL;

    };

    class Effect {

    public:

        Effect ();
        Effect (char*);
        ~Effect ();

    private:



    };

};
```

Audio.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Audio.h"

#include "SDL_audio.h"

namespace Audio {

    Audio::Audio () {

        //Default constructor

    }

    Audio::Audio (char *filename, char *channelName) {

        if (SDL_LoadWAV (filename, &this->wav_spec, &this->wav_buffer, &this->wav_length) == NULL) {

            std::cout << "[-] SDL: " << SDL_GetError () << "\n";

            exit (ERROR_SDL_AUDIO_WAV_LOAD);

        }

        this->device_id = SDL_OpenAudioDevice (channelName, 0, &this->wav_spec, NULL, 0);

        this->success = SDL_QueueAudio (this->device_id, this->wav_buffer, this->wav_length);

    }

    Audio::~Audio () {

        SDL_CloseAudioDevice (this->device_id);
        SDL_FreeWAV (this->wav_buffer); // <-- access violation here

    }

    void Audio::pause (int on) {

        SDL_PauseAudioDevice (this->device_id, on);

    }

};
```

Comment: Let me have a quick guess that somewhere a temporary object is made, which closes and frees your buffer when it dies. What happens if you implement a proper copy (or move) constructor?

Comment: See the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have a default constructor and didn't define your own, the C++ compiler gives you a `move constructor` and a `copy constructor` for free. They shallow-copy all members of the object.

When you use `operator=` (assignment of the object to another object), it uses the `copy` constructor. When you return a temporary object (rvalue), it uses the `move` constructor.

Sadly the default copy and move constructors don't fit you in this case.

Consider this:

```
Audio a = Audio("filename", "channel");
```

In this deceptively simple line of code you're:

1. Making a temporary (rvalue) `Audio` object
2. Calling `Audio::operator=`
3. Using the `move constructor`
4. Deleting the temporary object

So after this line of valid C++, `a` has:

1. `device_id` that was closed.
2. `wav_buffer` that was freed.

---

So how do we fix this?

```
Audio::Audio (char *filename, char *channelName) {
    if (SDL_LoadWAV (filename, &this->wav_spec, &this->wav_buffer, &this->wav_length) == NULL) {
        std::cout << "[-] SDL: " << SDL_GetError () << "\n";
        exit (ERROR_SDL_AUDIO_WAV_LOAD);
    }
    this->device_id = SDL_OpenAudioDevice (channelName, 0, &this->wav_spec, NULL, 0);
    this->success = SDL_QueueAudio (this->device_id, this->wav_buffer, this->wav_length);
}

Audio::Audio(Audio&& other) : // move constructor
    wav_length(other.wav_length),
    wav_buffer(other.wav_buffer),
    wav_spec(other.wav_spec),
    device_id(other.device_id),
    success(other.success)
{
    other.wav_buffer = nullptr;
}

Audio::~Audio () {
    if(wav_buffer != nullptr) {
        SDL_CloseAudioDevice (this->device_id);
        SDL_FreeWAV (this->wav_buffer); // Gives access violation
    }
}
```

Now when an `Audio` object is moved, its `wav_buffer` is nullified so that it won't be cleaned up when it's destroyed.

Comment: It looks like the problem was in fact the deconstor being called twice, because it was both being called in the program and when it’s closed. Although I will keep the copy constructor in mind if it’s needed.